# .btn Not Being Treated as a Button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my current project, any time I need to do something to all buttons, I need to separately target .btn. Every CSS selector for a button looks like `button, .btn` or `button:hover, .btn: hover`. All of the things I've given .btn to are buttons, so they should work if I just use the button selector, but they don't.

Comment: The other classes are either coming after your button styles or, look up 'css specificity'.

Comment: Awesome thanks! It was a specificity problem. I'm disappointed because that means that I can't save the keystrokes in CSS, but I'm glad I understand why.

Comment: I'm curious now. What do you mean by saving keystrokes in CSS?

Comment: I just would rather have my stylesheet be shorter. Now that it's all done it doesn't matter, but in the process of typing it out it feels like a lot of unecessary work to get around the specificity.